# useeffect not running on first mount but runs after first reload

Tags: reactjs

onStart is button and when i press it , it must run useeffect but it does not run it in first start but run it on reload. state value change on first start on dev tool.

```
const [started, setStarted] = useState(false);

const onStart = () => {
        setStarted(true);
      };

useEffect(() => {
    if(started){
    let timer = setInterval(() => tick(), 1000);
    return () =>  clearInterval(timer);
      }
  }, []);
```

Comment: Do you have a certain warning from eslint?

Comment: In addition to the correct answer below, you may also want to add `time` to your dependency array so that the interval continues to be called each update (based on your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70294040/how-to-pass-button-onclick-under-useeffect))

Comment: Thanks , it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `started` to the dependency array of the `useEffect`.

```js
const [started, setStarted] = useState(false);

const onStart = () => {
  setStarted(true);
};

useEffect(() => {
  if (started) {
    let timer = setInterval(() => tick(), 1000);
    return () =>  clearInterval(timer);
  }
}, [started]); // Add started here.
```

Comment: still runs one time only when i click start

Comment: Thanks it work , just want to add time too in dependency

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by adding time? I don't see anything called time in your code, other than the timer which is scoped to your useEffect function.